# Passing parameters of the object type in Java equivalent in Obj-C

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to convert the below method in JAVA to Objective-C

```
public static Object[] appendArray(Object[] objs,String...strings) {

      Object[] result= new Object[objs.length+strings.length];

      System.arraycopy(strings, 0, result, 0, strings.length);

      System.arraycopy(objs, 0, result, strings.length, objs.length);

      return result;
   }
```

When I wanted to translate this to obj-c is it going to be something like this:

```
 +(NSArray *)appendArray:(NSArray *)objs andStringField:(NSArray *)strings{
   }
```

Is there an equivalent of System.arraycopy for Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.arraycopy` makes a shallow copy so all it's doing is creating a new array. In your case you want to append 2 arrays together so you want to make an intermediate array that is mutable and then add the contents of both source arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *transient = [objs mutableCopy];
[transient addObjectsFromArray:strings];

return transient;
```